# Sensenet: fields referring external data

Tags: sensenet

I have requirement that consists to define one field of a document library that reference external data (outside of sensenet). Is it possible?

(I know that exists the reference type but it points to internal content of sensenet).

Answer (score 3):

There’s field type called [HyperLink](http://wiki.sensenet.com/HyperLink_Field) that can contain an outer reference/link.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to direct your visitor to an external site then you can use what Aniko has written.

If you want to show data from an outside system (e.g. via an api) you can for example implement a content representation of that data or custom evaluate it's fields. For this create a CTD with a custom [Content Handler](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Content_Handler) that fetches the data from the outside system and return it as a field value.

If you use this method I suggest to store and periodically refresh and show the data from sensenet instead of using live data transfer. It can be irritating or it could freeze your site if any connection problems occur.